# Sqlite 3 multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm working on my A2 coursework and I've run into a problem with multiple foreign keys. Here is all code I think is relevant, if you need more please reply saying so.

In TeacherInfo:

```
def TMenu():
print()
MenuPupil = menuClass.Menu("Teacher")
MenuPupil.printMenu()
Choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
if Choice == 1:
    db_name = "PupilPremiumTableNew.db"
    sql= """Create table TeacherInfo
        (TeacherID int,
        TeacherInitials text,
        TeacherYearTeaching int,
        primary key(TeacherID))"""
    CreateTeachersTable(db_name, "TeacherInfo",sql)
```

In PupilPremiumTableNew:

```
db_name = "PupilPremiumTableNew.db"
    sql= """Create table PupilPremiumTableNew
           (PupilID int,
            WritingGrade text,
            ReadingGrade text,
            MathsGrade text,
            Term text,
            RecordID int,
            InterventionsReading text,
            InterventionsWriting text,
            InterventionsMaths text,
            primary key(RecordID),
            foreign key(PupilID)
            references PupilInfo(PupilID)

            foreign key(TeacherID)
            references TeacherInfo (TeacherID)
            on update cascade on delete cascade)"""
    CreatePupilPremiumTable(db_name, "PupilPremiumTableNew",sql)


def CreateTeachersTable(db_name,table_name,sql):
with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name =?",(table_name,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    keep_table = True
    if len(result) == 1:
        response = input("The table {0} already exists, do you wish to recreate it?(y/n): ".format(table_name))
        if response == 'y':
            keep_table = False
            print("The table {0} has been recreated, all existing data has been deleted. ".format(table_name))
            cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
            db.commit()
        else:
            print("Existing table was kept. ")
    else:
        keep_table = False
    if not keep_table:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
```

The error I get says: `sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown column "TeacherID" in foreign key definition`

As you may notice a foreign key from another file, PupilTable is in there. At the moment that one works, if I remove TeacherID as a foreign key it all works

Thanks
Devilb77

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to tell it what TeacherID was, so to fix the issue I added TeacherID int, into the variable sql
Here is what it now looks like:

```
        db_name = "PupilPremiumTableNew.db"
    sql= """Create table PupilPremiumTableNew
           (PupilID int,
            WritingGrade text,
            ReadingGrade text,
            MathsGrade text,
            Term text,
            RecordID int,
            InterventionsReading text,
            InterventionsWriting text,
            InterventionsMaths text,
            TeacherID int,
            primary key(RecordID),
            foreign key(PupilID)
            references PupilInfo(PupilID)

            foreign key(TeacherID)
            references TeacherInfo (TeacherID)
            on update cascade on delete cascade)"""
    CreatePupilPremiumTable(db_name, "PupilPremiumTableNew",sql)
```